# Dual boot booting problems. Windows on UNEFI, Ubuntu on legacy

Tags: dual-boot

After installing dual boot I've noticed it doesn't load up the OS booting choice. Instead I need to access them through BIOS by changing boot options which is very annoying.
Both platforms are installed on same SSD. What are my options to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dual-booting with another OS, the two OSes' boot modes should match. Most computers that ship with Windows 8 and later use UEFI to boot that OS, so this configuration dictates use of UEFI mode when installing and booting Ubuntu.

So you have to match both your installations.

- Either renstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode or
- Convert Ubuntu into UEFI mode

Note: Do not follow this procedure if your computer is already booting correctly. Use this procedure only if you believe you've accidentally installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and you want it to boot in UEFI/UEFI mode.

Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab.

If you do not see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, this means that your PC does not have any UEFI partition. In this case, exit Boot-Repair, then create an UEFI partition (see the "Creating an UEFI partition" paragraph above).

If you see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, tick it then click the "Apply" button.

Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in UEFI mode (see the ""Set up the BIOS in UEFI or Legacy mode" paragraph above). [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)